# pyspark adding extra double quotes to strings containing double quotes

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I have code like the code below.  In my code, I'm reading a CSV into a pyspark dataframe.  the problem I'm running into is some of the columns in my CSV contain strings, that contain double quotes.  when my spark reads the CSV in, it's adding another set of quotes to the double quotes.  I've provided an example input quote and output quote below.  Can anyone suggest how to fix this?  I would like the string to be imported like the 'input string' below.

```
# sample input string
plywood 1 1/4" sheet

# sample output string
"plywood 1 1/4"" sheet"
```

Code:

```
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext
sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)

# read in df
df=sqlContext.read.csv('path')
```

Comment: How do you see `"plywood 1 1/4"" sheet"`? From `df.show()`? Or when you write it back data to another CSV? The question is not clear and we can't reproduce it with the given code snippet.

Comment: @blackbishop with .show() or when I write it out to parquet files, and query from redshift (it's part of etl process), in both cases it displays as "plywood 1 1/4"" sheet".  so I traced it back to that first initial step where it reads the csv in to the dataframe.  it's adding the extra double quotes.